# Do php string functions assume automatic casting?

Tags: php, casting, string-function

I´m dealing with Sabre/vobject. To read property values it is necessary to do a casting:

```
echo (string)$vcard->FN;
```

I forgot that a few times and observed that for example:

```
$number = str_replace("\xc2\xa0", "\x20", $card->TEL);
$name = strtoupper($card->FN);
```

still works.

The PHP manual [says](https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting):

> "...String conversion is automatically done in the scope of an
>   expression where a string is needed. This happens when using the echo
>   or print functions, or when a variable is compared to a string..."

However, I have found no reference to the fact that this also applies to string functions.

Comment: The first sentence explains that: _"String conversion is automatically done in the scope of an expression where a string is needed"_. In your `str_replace()`, the third argument needs to be a string or an array. If you pass in something other than an array, it will try and convert it to string. In your `echo` example, you shouldn't need to convert it to string either, like the second sentence says.

Comment: Der "echo" line isn´t mine but from [sabre/vobject documentation](http://sabre.io/vobject/vcard/) ->Reading property values! Although this is contrary to the PHP manual, it only works in that way (with explicit casting).

Comment: If you do a `var_dump($vcard->FN);`, what do you get? What type does the value have?

Comment: Sorry Magnus, that's not the question

Comment: I never said that answered the question. It's just basic debugging. If we know what datatype the value has, then we can figure out why you need to cast it when echoing it and not when using `str_replace()`, since that's not the common behavior. The more info we get, the more likely it is for us to be able to reproduce the issue and answer the actual question.